# Uploading a file using PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a front end php application that is connected to an API. The application talks to the API through PHP curl as that is the only mode of communication.

I need to upload files to the server, these files are taken from the browser and sent to the server.

What would be the best way to send a multi part file to the server using curl.

Currently i am sending the file using  $_POST , but i dont think that is recommended.

Comment: Do you have control over the API? If not, does the API spec say anything about the method of uploading stuff?

Comment: well, i do have control over the api, but the developer just used the basic POST variable, ofcourse that would need to be changed, but i need to make sure, if it works from the front end

Answer (score 1):

If your using curl POST then you can just add the file to the POST with @

```
// same as <input type="file" name="fileField">
$post = array(
    "fileField"=>"@/path/to/file.jpg",
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

There are plenty of results on [google](http://bit.ly/LlSMy9)

Comment: Just a note that it is necesarry to pass the "filefield" as an array. If it is passed explicitly like "`filefield=@path-to_file`", it won't work.